# ng2 stomp client unsubscribe() not working

Tags: angular, stomp

I am subscribing to a socket using ng2-stomp-service:

```
this.fooSubscription = this.stomp.subscribe('/topic/foo', (res) => {
    console.log('do stuff with res');
});
```

This works great to receive data.  But at some point (when a button is clicked) I would like to stop receiving the data.  The connection is still being used by other subscriptions, so I'd just like to unsubscribe this specific subscriptions.  I have this happening when the button is clicked:

```
unsubscribeFoo() {
    this.fooSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

However, I am still clearly getting data coming from this subscription as it's sent from the server.

when I unsubscribe, I see this in my browser console from stomp's debug output, which looks promising:

```
>>> UNSUBSCRIBE
id:sub-3
```

But alas, I still get data just moments later.

Comment: I have same issue, do you found any fixing?

Comment: @Mardari nope, I ended up simply opening multiple connections and creating a single subscription on each, allowing me to stop the data flow of individual subscriptions by disconnecting the specific connection.  There must be a better way, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but for anyone who stumbles across this, the unsubscribe function references the id of the topic, not the actual topic.

You can set the id in the subscribe function:

```
client.subscribe(topic, messageHandler, { id: “myTopicId”});
```

Now you can call unsubscribe like this:

```
client.unsubscribe(“myTopicId”);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to disconnect stomp as such when button is clicked:

```
this.stomp.disconnect();
```

What you did should cause the console message 'do stuff with res' to stop coming through but that won't disconnect the stomp client.

If the above doesn't work, try going through all stompclient subscriptions and unsubscribing before disconnecting stompClient

```
for (const sub in this.stomp.subscriptions) {
  if (this.stomp.subscriptions.hasOwnProperty(sub)) {
    this.stomp.unsubscribe(sub);
  }
}
```

I have been using stompJs directly (not ng2-stomp) and this has been working for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't disconnect since I still have other subscriptions that are actively receiving data, and I can't stop those.  All the subscriptions are using the same connection.  I just want to stop the data coming from one specific subscription.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with `@stomp/stompjs` and Spring Boot which ended up being a problem in the handling of incoming subscriptions on the back-end.

Whenever a `SUBSCRIBE` message came in, the back-end would do a "blocking" request to fetch additional data. Only after this additional request finished it would start handling the next `SUBSCRIBE` message.

If this request takes a while to complete, or when a lot of `SUBSCRIBE` messages are coming in, the `UNSUBSCRIBE` message sent out by the client arrives before the relevant `SUBSCRIBE` message would be handled. That means the `UNSUBSCRIBE` doesn't do anything and a little while later the `SUBSCRIBE` message is handled anyway and starts producing messages without ever stopping.

The fix for this would be to handle that additional request in the back-end asynchronously. Removing the request resolved the issue, which confirmed our suspicions.

Not 100% sure this is the same root cause but I'm hoping it helps others who run into a similar issue.

More context can be found in [stomp-js/stompjs#370](https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs/issues/370).